# where is images/image.jpg?

Tags: images, html, directory

I am being forced to use a SOAP service on a site, and for some of the UI elements it is calling images that I have to put in place.

I can't point them to a theme folder, as I have no control over the HTML, and I am reluctant to use javascript.

the code points to `<img src="images/image.jpg" >`, I have tried adding an images folder to the root of my WP installation, to no avail.

So my question is where should I put the image so that the HTML can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin is search for an 'images' folder inside the current working directory. For example if you are in `/blogs/`, a file looking for `images/image.jpg` is actually looking for `/blogs/images/image.jpg`. This can obviously get *very* messy when re-writing URLs with stuff like `/2010/03/blog-title` so actually put an image in the specific location is impossible, you will need to edit HTML or at least .htaccass to resolve it.

Look up: `<base>` tag, mod-rewrites, javascript or editing whatever plugin is creating that HTML (str_replace on the output?). Personally I think you need to look into filtering the HTML you're receiving from the SOAP service to clear that up.